# Meaning of Africanderdom

Tags: meaning

Good evening,

I have a question I wanted to know,what does "africanderdom " mean ? 
I can't find its meaning on the Internet.
I only know that it was invented by Hobson.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide context; at what link does this word appear, and what is the surrounding text? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] review the [help] for additional guidance on writing strong questions.

Comment: Where did you look on the internet, the first results on bing and google take you to a good definition..

Comment: Generally speaking, the suffix "-dom", when applied to a term for a group of people, implies the encompassing "society" or "nation" of those people.  Hence "Christendom".

Comment: [**Africander**](https://archive.org/stream/africanderismsgl00pett/africanderismsgl00pett_djvu.txt) — *This word has been used with a variety of sig- 
nifications : (1) African-born descendants of European parents 
generally, (2) African-born offspring of Dutch parents only, (3) 
Coloured people of mixed blood. Often enough the word is 
used adjectivally with an equal number of similar significa- 
tions. In recent years an effort has been made to limit its 
meanmg to (1) or (2).* The ***-ism*** suffix is still productive, and the way it's used can easily be looked up.

Answer (score 3):

**Coming from South African English, Africanderdom means:**

> 1. The Afrikaner people; Afrikaners collectively, esp. in a nationalistic or political sense
> 2. The ethos of the Afrikaner people; Afrikaner nationalism;

You can read more about it [here](https://www.dsae.co.za/#!/search/hws/africanderdom/sN/pN).

Also written as: Afrikanderdom and Afrikanerdom

Comment: Why not include the spelling in your answer?  Perhaps the reason the OP did not find it was his/her misspelling...

Comment: It was the correct spelling, but I've added it in. The reason OP didn't find it, is that it isn't a common word. I searched the word with double quotes around it and found different entries.

Comment: The word did appear with a "c" in some sources in the late 19th and early 20th centuries, presumably because some writers in English felt that the spelling should match English "Africa" rather than Afrikaans/Dutch "Afrika". Examples: [this](https://bit.ly/2IqqHbV), [this](https://bit.ly/2ImZCWR), and [this](https://bit.ly/2Ir2hz4).

Comment: The link given in this answer shows (on the left hand side) alternative spellings - Africaaner and Africanderdom, both of which link to the quoted spelling - Afrikanderdom.